# What is the difference in the two not equal operator in php?

Tags: php

There are two not equal operator `!=` and `<>`. Are they the same thing? Or are they slightly different from one another?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php same thing I would say

Comment: In my opinion, use `!=` to More similarity to other C-Base languages.

Comment: @RC. I'm sorry for a bit off from question, it was really impressed me., however, similarly, what is difference between `Null` and `Empty`? Thanks.

Comment: @HouyNarun `null` is a value, `empty` is a function (checking for anything, that would cast to 0/null/'')

Comment: @Jakumi, `empty` here I meant `if $var==''` because in php and some other language I've known it is a bit confusing between `if $var == Null` vs. `if $var == ''`. is it the same thing or different? Thanks.

Comment: @HouyNarun I believe it depends on type-casting. php tries to type-cast when it comes to basic types. however, if you want to make the distinction, you should use a function like `empty()` (type agnostic "empty" value), `is_null()` (the var is truly null) or strict comparison (`===`). most of the time there is some edge case that should be avoided.

Comment: @Jakumi, I got it now. Thanks very much for your detail collaboration. :)

Answer (score 1):

They are equal: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

```
$a != $b    // Not equal    TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.
$a <> $b    // Not equal    TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.
$a !== $b // Not identical  TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of the same type.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. You can use both in MSSQL.

[The MSSQL doc says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-exclamation)

> `!=` functions the same as the `<>` (Not Equal To) comparison
>   operator.

But `<>` is defined in the [ANSI 99 SQL standard](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~len/sql1999.pdf) and `!=` is not. So not all DB engines may support it and if you want to generate portable code I recommend using `<>.`

Comment: where does mssql come from? question's tag is php ;o)