# return array_filter($data, fn($datum) => $datum != null); removes false and 0s

Tags: php, arrays

How do I make the `array_filter` method return keys with 0 and false but ignore NULLs?

When I ran without `array_filter`, this is what I get:

```json
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "1st Floor",
   "facility": {...},
   "owner": null,
   "is_parking": false,
   "is_divisible": true,
   "leasable_space": 200,
   "common_space": 0,
   "landlord_space": 0,
   "total_space": 200
}
```

When I ran it `array_filter` I get this:

```json
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "1st Floor",
   "facility": {...},
   "is_divisible": true,
   "leasable_space": 200,
   "total_space": 200
}
```

I expected owner to go but `is_parking`, `common_space`, and `landlord_space` to remain with their respective values.

Is there a way I can fix this or optional method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference in the two not equal operator in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249773/what-is-the-difference-in-the-two-not-equal-operator-in-php)

Comment: Although the duplicate is about ==, != also does 'type juggling' for comparisons.

Comment: How to fix it - `$datum !== null`

Comment: I'll be damned. It was right there. @NigelRen add it as answer I nark it.